# Passing ArrayList as value only and not reference

Tags: java, reference, arraylist, pass-by-reference

Simply put, I have a method with an ArrayList parameter. In the method I modify the contents of the ArrayList for purposes relevant only to what is returned by the method. Therefore, I do not want the ArrayList which is being passed as the parameter to be affected at all (i.e. not passed as a reference).

Everything I have tried has failed to achieve the desired effect. What do I need to do so that I can make use of a copy of the ArrayList within the method only, but not have it change the actual variable?

Comment: You could pass [`Collections#unmodifiable(yourList)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) in order to send an unmodifiable copy of your list.

Comment: You could also create a new copy of the `ArrayList` in the method that is modifying it.  While it won't effect the first `ArrayList`, any objects you change within will still be changed...

Comment: Are you modifying the list only? Or also what is inside of the list?

Comment: Does anyone know if System.arraycopy will just copy the references or clone the objects in the array as well?? I looked for the source and ran into an end because it's a native method..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Even if you had a way to pass the array list as a copy and not by reference it would have been only a shallow copy.

I would do something like:

```
void foo(final ArrayList list) {

    ArrayList listCopy = new ArrayList(list);
    // Rest of the code

}
```

And just work on the copied list.

Comment: That will do it. I originally tried setting the internal list equal to the parameter, but that didn't work. This is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: Indeed, there is a required waiting period before being able to accept an answer.

Comment: It doesn't work when you have list of object! by changing objects as they are not final the list has changed too.

Answer (score 22):

You can create a copy of the ArrayList using ArrayList's copy constructor:

```
ArrayList copy = new ArrayList(original);
```

But if the elements of the list are also objects, then you must be aware that modifying a member of the copy will also modify that member in the original.

Comment: how would you make it so that modifying a member of the copy won't modify the original list?

Comment: To answer @Arjun, I think for the scenario you mentioned, it would require a deep copy, instead of a shallow copy

Answer (score 6):

You could pass [`Collections#unmodifiableList(yourList)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) in order to send an unmodifiable copy of your list. By the way, your `List<Whatever>` is passed by value since [Java always pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197), note that in `foo(List<Whatever> list)` method you can not modify the `list` value but **you can modify its contents**.

```
public class MyClass {

    List<Whatever> list = new ArrayList<Whatever>();

    public void bar() {
        //filling list...
        foo(Collections.unmodifiableList(list));
    }

    public void foo(List<Whatever> list) {
        //do what you want with list except modifying it...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `.clone` method or a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` to make a copy, thereby not impacting the original.

Comment: IMHO, that seems excessive, what's wrong with `new ArrayList(list)`?

Comment: IMHO = "in my honest opinion"

Answer (score 3):

Try this in you method :

```
void method(List<Integer> list) {
        List copyList =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
        copyList.addAll(list); // This will create a copy of all the emlements of your original list
    }
```

Comment: Better yet do `new ArrayList<Integer>(list)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure on why, even after `new ArrayList<MyObj>(old)` the object was still changing reference in places it wasn't supposed to. So I had to instantiate a new copy of the objects inside.

I made a copy constructor like the one on the ArrayList and did like

```
 newArray = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
        for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.size(); i++) {
            newArray.add(new MyObj(ondArray.get(i)));
        }
```

Just hope to help someone else if the answer from Avi is not enough in your case, like mine with a code too messy to even understand =P

Answer (score 1):

Just clone it.

```
public ArrayList cloneArrayList(ArrayList lst){
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=0; i<lst.size(); i++){
        list.add(lst.get(i));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Add suggested in the comments, you can also use

```
ArrayList copy = new ArrayList(original);
```

and also

```
ArrayList copy = new ArrayList();
copy.addAll(original);
```

Comment: IMHO, that seems excessive, what's wrong with `new ArrayList(list)`?

Comment: I don't know of the existance of `new ArrayList(list)`. Sorry.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Don't be sorry for learning something new

Answer (score 0):

On the lines of the existing answers but using the ArrayList API. You can use `subList(fromIndex, toIndex)` method. It explicitly creates a view of the list with only desired elements (of course, in sequence). Here, even if you modify the view with add/remove etc operations, it won't change the original list. It saves you from explicitly creating a copy.

Something like this:

```
public void recursiveMethod(List<Integer> list) {
    if(base)
         return;
    recursiveCall(list);

    // following will just create a tail list but will not actually modify the list
    recursiveCall(list.subList(1, list.size());
}
```