# Clearing a global ArrayList clears an other too

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a really weird bug.

I am programming a generic class and in one of its method, there is a strange thing. Here the class code (not completely):

```
public abstract class GenericFragment<M extends BaseModel, A extends BaseAdapter> extends HtmlFragment {

    private ArrayList<M> datas = new ArrayList<>();    
    private A adapter;

    protected abstract String getUrl();

    protected abstract A setAdapter();

    protected A getAdapter() {

        if(adapter == null) {
             adapter = setAdapter();
        }

        return adapter;
    }

    protected ArrayList<M> getDatas() {
        return datas;
    }

    protected void refreshData(ArrayList<M> datas) {

        Log.d("before glob", String.valueOf(this.datas.size()));
        Log.d("before loc", String.valueOf(datas.size()));

        this.datas.clear();

        Log.d("clear glob", String.valueOf(this.datas.size()));
        Log.d("clear loc", String.valueOf(datas.size()));

        this.datas.addAll(datas);

        Log.d("after glob", String.valueOf(this.datas.size()));
        Log.d("after loc", String.valueOf(datas.size()));

        getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And when I call the function `refreshData()` the global `ArrayList` is cleared but also the local `ArrayList`. Here are the logs:

```
D/niviel: before glob: 5
D/niviel: before loc: 5
D/niviel: clear glob: 0
D/niviel: clear loc: 0
D/niviel: after glob: 0
D/niviel: after loc: 0
```

I just want to clone the local array to the global array.

EDIT:

The function is called in a child class.

```
requestData(activity, new requestDataCallback() {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<? extends BaseModel> parseDatas(Document document) {
        return RecordProvider.getRecord(activity, document);
    }

    @Override
    public void runOnUIThread(ArrayList<? extends BaseModel> datas) {

        refreshData((ArrayList<Record>) datas);
    }

});
```

Comment: What parameter are you passing to `refreshData`? If it is `this.datas`, why wouldn't you expect it to clear "both" `this.datas` and `datas`? ("both", because it's the same instance).

Comment: Was the class field set in the setter and used in refreshData?

Comment: how do you pass the arraylist or how do you copy from global arraylist

Comment: The arraylist comes from a callback and the function is called in a child class in a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally debugged my code. I noticed that the function `refreshData()` was passing in parameters the global ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

In your refreshData(), both the lists u are using are same.

```
protected void refreshData(ArrayList<M> datas) {

Log.d("before glob", String.valueOf(this.datas.size()));
Log.d("before loc", String.valueOf(datas.size()));

//here you are clearing datas
this.datas.clear();

//so now your datas size will be 0

Log.d("clear glob", String.valueOf(this.datas.size()));
Log.d("clear loc", String.valueOf(datas.size()));

//here you are adding it to datas again whose size is already 0
this.datas.addAll(datas);

Log.d("after glob", String.valueOf(this.datas.size()));
Log.d("after loc", String.valueOf(datas.size()));

getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how they can be the same: even if I change the local array's name, there is still the problem

Answer (score 0):

Learn about Java memory model. List is reference type of data, so you work with the same list.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your fast answer. So according to you, what is the best way the solve the problem ?

Comment: For example you can use [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778645/passing-arraylist-as-value-only-and-not-reference)  
Also would be very nice if you provide part of code where you use refreshData function.

Comment: the problem is if I make a new array, the adapter won't work, will it ?

Comment: You have 1 ArrayList which added to adapter, if you change different ArrayList or its copy, then ofc no changes in your adapter would apear.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I use clear and addAll. All I want is to replace the global array with the local one in order to call notifydatasetchanged

Comment: You can call notifyDataSetChanged any time you want.